# Could not ping Solaris KVM Guest from another computer

Tags: 12.04, networking, command-line, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I setup Solaris Guest using KVM in Ubuntu. I don't have problem pinging host (Ubuntu) to guest (Solaris) and vice versa. Also my Solaris guest can ping other computers in my network but not the other way around. Below is the network configuration I have:

Host ifconfig

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ac:6f:24:6b:e5
          inet addr:192.168.23.133  Bcast:192.168.23.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::baac:6fff:fe24:6be5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:61723 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:5869388 (5.8 MB)  TX bytes:83437 (83.4 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ac:6f:24:6b:e5
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:64919 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1032 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7268230 (7.2 MB)  TX bytes:141407 (141.4 KB)
          Interrupt:21 Memory:fe6e0000-fe700000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:11874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2883265 (2.8 MB)  TX bytes:2883265 (2.8 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:55:66:b4:cc:68
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:67:d6:ca
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe67:d6ca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:83 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:54663 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:13254 (13.2 KB)  TX bytes:5919041 (5.9 MB)
```

and this is for host /etc/network/interfaces

```
#Loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#eth0 interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

#virtual bridge
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

I have read these sites [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179508/kvm-bridged-network-not-working) and [link2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking) but still after numerous configuration changes including adding br0 on /etc/network/interfaces, I still can't ping my Solaris guest from another computer. Can anyone give me advice on this? Thanks in advance.

## Update

After tinkering with various configuration i was able to ping Solaris VM from another computer, Host (Ubuntu) to Guest(Solaris) vice versa. The configuration above is a working configuration. I hope this is helpful for others who encountered the same problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify whether the `ifconfig` output you show is on the guest or the host. Whichever it is, please also add the output of `ifconfig` on the other (we need both host and guest output). Also tell us exactly how you are attempting to ping, IP? Hostname?

Comment: duplicate with [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/527609/cannot-ping-kvm-windows-guest-from-host-only)?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue.
Few findings from my side:

1. Booted Plain Opensolaris VM, found same issue!
2. Checked with qemu's site on supported OSes, Solaris 11 Express 2010.11 is supported but with few issues.
3. Then found this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1395217

Solution: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1040500