# Cannot ping KVM Windows guest from host only

Tags: 14.04, kvm-virtualization, ping

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 machine which uses KVM to host a Windows guest. After a restart I am now unable to ping the Windows guest from the host machine, to confirm everything was working perfectly up until I restarted the host. I can ping the guest from every other PC on the LAN and the guest can communicate with the host without any problems. It is only the host that cannot talk to the guest.

This is the contents of /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    bridge_ports eth1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fs 0
    bridge_maxwait 5
```

This is the output from ifconfig

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:a4:4c:2c:81:1b  
      inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::62a4:4cff:fe2c:811b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:897122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:770399 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:251836869 (251.8 MB)  TX bytes:201878124 (201.8 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:a4:4c:2c:81:1b  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:343226 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:205432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:100974693 (100.9 MB)  TX bytes:43641794 (43.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:342809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:342809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:750030721 (750.0 MB)  TX bytes:750030721 (750.0 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:6a:76:55:18:28  
      inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:b7:d7:c6  
      inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:feb7:d7c6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:90900 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:94214 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
      RX bytes:26204675 (26.2 MB)  TX bytes:33808944 (33.8 MB)
```

Output from brctl show

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.60a44c2c811b   no          eth1
                                        vnet0
virbr0      8000.000000000000   yes
```

The guest uses a bridge network to br0

UPDATE: After a bit more investigation it looks like it might be something to do with the bridge adapter

This is the output from arp -n

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.0.69             ether   1c:3e:84:e6:65:cd   C                     br0
192.168.0.128            ether   e8:99:c4:a0:e8:f8   C                     br0
192.168.0.153            ether   d0:27:88:47:02:02   C                     br0
192.168.0.1              ether   34:8a:ae:bf:c0:0e   C                     br0
192.168.0.4              ether   52:54:00:b7:d7:c6   C                     br0
192.168.0.75             ether   52:54:00:98:e5:4c   C                     br0
```

As you can see 192.168.0.4 which is the IP that I am trying to contact is on interface br0. 192.168.0.75 also belongs to the same machine and I cannot ping this either. All the other IPs are other machines on the network and I can ping those without any error

This is the output from ping

```
ping 192.168.0.4
PING 192.168.0.4 (192.168.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

There is no response from the ping ever. It stays as above with a blinking cursor forever

Comment: duplicate with [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/462763/could-not-ping-solaris-kvm-guest-from-another-computer)? sorry that there aren't any answers there

Comment: Which IP address you use to try to connect to the VM?

Comment: @Salem 192.168.0.4

Comment: `eth1` is using a static IP or DHCP?

Comment: @Salem I believe eth1 is DHCP

Comment: What's the actual error you see when trying to ping?

Comment: @Jan there is no error. The ping never resolves. 100% packet loss

Comment: @Jan see updates

Answer (score 1):

I think in general newer versions of Windows (from XP onwards) by default do not respond to ping (for security purpose).

To see whether the network works, it's easier to ping from the Windows side to the Linux host.

Should you insist to ping from host to the guest, you need to open the firewall in the Windows side and activate the ping service, e.g. for [Windows 7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-enable-ping-response-in-windows-7/5aff5f8d-f138-4c9a-8646-5b3a99f1cae6). You need to enable incoming ICMP packets.