# KVM Bridged network not working for 2 guests

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I have a bridged network setup and working, following the guides

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

and

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking

My setup is similar to this question:
[KVM Bridged Network Not Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179508/kvm-bridged-network-not-working), but I can successfully ssh into the guest machine using its ip.

When I create a second device, following the same process as before (the one in the accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179508/kvm-bridged-network-not-working)), it also works successfully: I can ping to-and-from it, and I can ssh into it. The problem is that the two guest machines doesn't work at the same time. If the one has networking, the other one doens't, and vica versa.

All of the computers on my network are receiving IPs from the DHCP server, and it successfully assigns IPs to my guests if they are not switched on at the same time.

Should I be creating the guests in a different way if I want them to be bridged at the same time?

Details about my setup:

`ifconfig`

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:ae:8b:0e:6d  
          inet addr:192.168.14.111  Bcast:192.168.14.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:aeff:fe8b:e6d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:678 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:200635 (200.6 KB)  TX bytes:231362 (231.3 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0a:cd:1c:71:fd  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:ae:8b:0e:6d  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2191 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:792 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:234455 (234.4 KB)  TX bytes:248498 (248.4 KB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:963 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:963 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:295031 (295.0 KB)  TX bytes:295031 (295.0 KB)                                                     

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:4f:df:90                                                              
          inet addr:192.168.100.1  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0                                         
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                                                                 
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                         
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                       
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                                                                  
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)                                                                     

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:6a:11:7f                                                              
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe6a:117f/64 Scope:Link                                                          
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                                                         
          RX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                        
          TX packets:941 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                     
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:2516 (2.5 KB)  TX bytes:91292 (91.2 KB)

vnet1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:bc:8c:ed  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:febc:8ced/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:42 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:919 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:7988 (7.9 KB)  TX bytes:85304 (85.3 KB)
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
   bridge_ports eth1
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_fd 0
   bridge_maxwait 0
#   post-up ip link set br0 address 00:23:ae:8b:0e:6d
```

`brctl show`

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.0023ae8b0e6d       no              eth1
                                                        vnet0
                                                        vnet1
virbr0          8000.5254004fdf90       yes             virbr0-nic
```

`ip route`

```
default via 192.168.14.1 dev br0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.14.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.14.111 
192.168.100.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.100.1
```

I am using `eth1`, `eth0` is a second network card that is unused.

The `ifconfig` of the first virtual machine is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bc:8c:ed  
          inet addr:192.168.14.150  Bcast:192.168.14.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:febc:8ced/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26341 errors:0 dropped:9 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:35241526 (35.2 MB)  TX bytes:905257 (905.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                        
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                      
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                                                                  
          RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)
```

The `ifconfig` of the second virtual machine is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:17:cc:ef  
          inet addr:192.168.14.148  Bcast:192.168.14.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe17:ccef/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29695 errors:0 dropped:11 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13566 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:35556206 (35.5 MB)  TX bytes:944517 (944.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)
```

The machines work fine when they are only running one at a time, but they can't both be pinged at the same time. The connection seems to jump between them, favouring whichever is busy doing stuff on the network.

Comment: Could you add to your question the `ifconfig` outputs for the two guest VMs.

Comment: Sure thing, will start up the VMs again tomorrow and include it.

Comment: Added the `ifconfig` of the two VMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a hardware issue.

The server I was experimenting with had the following network card (from `lshw -C network`):

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 00:0a:cd:1c:71:fd
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=half latency=64 link=no maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:cc00(size=256) memory:dfbff000-dfbff0ff
```

I repeated the exact same setup as described in the question, on a newer computer, with the following network card:

```
  *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 05
   serial: 90:b1:1c:81:83:be
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:44 memory:fbf00000-fbf1ffff memory:fbf29000-fbf29fff ioport:f040(size=32)
```

And the bridge worked as expected; both VMs now showed up on the network as physical devices and both worked at the same time.